# Git force push --force --all does not update all branches

Tags: git, gitlab, push

I am doing a hard delete of a file in my gitlab repo.  I have 3 branches where i want this file to be removed from the commits.

My understanding with git is not that great

I have run the below command to completely remove any reference of a particular file from all of branches in my repo and they are all rewritten.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch fileA.sh" -- --all
```

i ran then ran the below commands to clean up the repo on my local

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Below are  the branches that I hae , along side the remote-tracking branches

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mbyousaf2020-master-patch-95874
  remotes/origin/test
```

However, when running the  `git push --all --force` it is only updating the master branch on my repo. How do I also update the remaining remote-tracking branches?

```
:qabash $ git push --all --force
Enumerating objects: 316, done.
Counting objects: 100% (316/316), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
Writing objects: 100% (314/314), 30.10 KiB | 10.03 MiB/s, done.
Total 314 (delta 195), reused 276 (delta 188)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (195/195), completed with 1 local object.
To gitlab.com:qa.git
 + a28475e...40053dd master -> master (forced update)
```

What command do i need to run that it updates all my branches and completely removes any reference of the file in all my branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself, when you listed the branches:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mbyousaf2020-master-patch-95874
  remotes/origin/test
```

The `remotes/origin` branches are not yours; they are remote-tracking branches. *You* only have *one* branch — `master`. Therefore `git push --all` pushes all the branches you have, namely that one branch, `master`. Git is behaving exactly as expected.

> I have 3 branches where i want this file to be removed from the commits.

No, you don't. You yourself have proved that you have only one branch, namely `master`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. But then what command would i run to update all the ```remotes/origin```  tracking branches ?

Comment: @BilalYousaf: You do this like you _did_ it for master, just with the difference that you need to pull those branches first to have them "your own" (within your local git repository). To get comfortable with that, you can try some of the chapters in the git-book which is available online for free.

Comment: You would create a local branch based on the remote-tracking branch, edit it, and push it.

Comment: On my machine, if I were to say `git switch develop`, Git would create the `develop` branch based on the `origin/develop` remote-tracking branch and would configure the latter as the upstream of the former.